# receive mouse event in a python program

Tags: python, macos, mouse

I would like to receive an event on mouse click / release, with its position on the screen, in a python program on a mac. How can I achieve that ?

Ideally I would like to be able to prevent default action on this click (such as `e.preventDefault()` in web development).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pynput` does the job.

```py
from pynput.mouse import Listener

with Listener(on_click=print) as listener:
    listener.join()
```